# Quartz Composer Switch Layers (Origami)

Tags: quartz-graphics, prototyping, quartz-composer, origami

I'm making an app prototype in QC using origami. It consists of jpgs that are being switched whenever a click is made. The problem I'm having is that I cannot set specific hit area as it creates a layer on top and the hit area stays on top of the layers below and as the buttons are at the same place, it's impossible to switch to next image.

Right now I have just set it so the image slides to the right revealing the layer below but I need a specific hit area.

Is anyone have any idea on how to do that? I attached screenshot with what I have right now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6HZB.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract your interaction. Count each click and use that to switch between the image you want to show. You can use a Counter patch and increment and decrement its internal count as needed.